Can We Analyse a Verbless Clause as a Direct Object?
I was recently reading George R.R. Martin's Fire and Blood, and I came upon this sentence:

The coming of the new year found Maegor still without a son, not even a bastard who might be legitimized.

The part I would like to draw your attention to is 'Maegor still without a son,' which I have italicised. To me, this looks like a verbless clause, a shortened version of 'Maegor was still without a son,' so I'm wondering what the best way to analyse this sentence is.
Does it contain a verbless clause functioning as a direct object of 'found'? Or is 'Maegor' the direct object and 'still without a son' a prepositional phrase functioning as a complement or adjunct? The latter is supported by the fact it can be made passive, as in 'Maegor was found still without a son.'
In Oxford Modern English Grammar, the author, Bas Aarts, states, perhaps controversially, that a participle clause can function as a direct object, as in 'The administrators recommended Jill carrying out this project.' This would support the idea of a verbless clause receiving the same treatment.

It's not a clause, and the verb found directly precedes the phrase.

The coming of the new year found Maegor lamenting his lack of a son would be the equivalent to The administrators recommended Jill carrying out this project. But I don't see anything "controversial" about participle clauses functioning as direct objects. I heard the dog barking looks to me like the same basic construction. And for a "verbless" direct object, I saw a dog with three legs seems to fit the bill - it's not really "shortened" from a dog had three legs, though.
